# return all results in mysql/sql using format where equals wildcard

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wildcard, where-clause

how do I put together an sql that will return ALL values with a **wild card**
example:

> WHERE fieldname = 'ALL'

I tried the wild card % and the * and none of them worked.
I know I can do a query that returns all values but this is for a search filter and I need to have that option to use it in that format and the format is :

> WHERE fieldname ='all';

or

> maybe WHERE fieldname ='%';

the latter didn't work btw. any suggestions please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write condition as:
for finding string all.

```
WHERE fieldname like '%all%';
```

for finding any string

```
 WHERE fieldname like '%';
```

Comment: +1 Note that null values of fieldname will **not** be matched by `fieldname like '%'`.